# Highcharts version 8.2.0 tilemap doesn't support "square" shape

Tags: highcharts, shapes, square

I've been using highcharts 7.2.0 **tilemap** chart, but after updating to version 8.2.0, I'm getting an error when **tileShape** is set to *"square"*

In my `https://jsfiddle.net/nqxm2yk7/1/` , **tileShape** is set to *'circle'*, but if you change it to "square", it will be crash.

Although the official [documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/tilemap-series#squaremaps) says, that we can use four different types of shapes

[image: Official page screenshot]

Is anyone has the same problem?

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/nqxm2yk7/1/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want square tiles you will need to set the chart type to "heatmap":

```
chart: {
    type: 'heatmap',
    height: '120%'
},
```

and also include heatmap.js

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whippet71/5yv9detg/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I found that it is a regression and I reported it on the Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14267. If you need a temporary workaround please ask in the comment for it - the core developers will take care of your case.